# gnu-parallel encrypting files with spaces or special characters?

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to encrypt a bunch of files with the code below:

```
find . -name "*.vi" | sort | parallel --gnu -j 4 --workdir "$PWD" '
    echo "Encrypting {/.} ..."
    gpg -r user@myemail.com -o "/tank/test/{/.}.gpg" -e "{}"
';
```

This works fine, but only if the filenames have no spaces nor special characters (! or ') in them.
Other than re-naming all the files, is there a way to make this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like too much quoting. Remember that GNU Parallel assumes {} is being parsed directly by the shell. Try removing "" around {} and {/.}:

```
# Avoid typing --gnu ever again
echo '--gnu' >> ~/.parallel/config

find . -name "*.vi" | sort |
  parallel echo Encrypting {/.} ...";" gpg -r user@myemail.com -o /tank/test/{/.}.gpg -e {}
```

Comment: Works! The resulting filenames have their spaces replaced by "\" but that's no problem, i can just run a rename command after that.
Thanks man!

Comment: Then you have not removed enough ". Remove more. Remember {} and {/.} should *never* be inside " or '.